# Using Identity DbContext and DbContext in a class library in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 solution which contains a class library project and an ASP.NET MVC project. The MVC project reference the class library. Class library has all the entity classes and DbContext using EF Core. Everything was fine up to that.

Then I added ASP.NET Identity to the MVC project. It creates a separate IdentityDbContext to create the identity-related entities. I want relationships (foreign keys) between the Identity user entity and some of my other entities (I am using code first migrations). And I don't want to do migrations twice from both DbContextes. What is the correct approach to use here?

Answer (score 1):

Combine your two contexts into one. In other words, just make your original context inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, instead of `DbContext` and dump the one the Identity scaffold created for you.